# Rails: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

I have the following code (somewhat simplified ...

```
create_table :signatures do |t|
  t.integer :signer_id
  t.integer :card_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

With the models looking like ...

```
class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :card
    belongs_to :user
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :signatures
    has_many :signers, :through => :signatures, :foreign_key => "card_id"
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :sent_cards, :class_name => "Card", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
    has_many :received_cards, :class_name => "Card", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"

    has_many :signatures
    has_many :signed_cards, :through => :signatures, :foreign_key => "signer_id"

end
```

I see the following error using the rails console ...

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > u15.signed_cards
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :signed_card or :signed_cards in model Signature. Try 'has_many :signed_cards, :through => :signatures, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :card or :user?
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:517:in `check_validity!'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:27:in `initialize'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:164:in `new'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:164:in `association'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:41:in `block in define_readers'
    from (irb):11
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/slabounty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I get the same thing when I do add the `source => :card/:user` (should be :card in this case I believe).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

---

Showing a partial solution because I wanted to clean up a
few things. The migration remained the same as the previous version. I'm now
seeing a SQL error (see below) where it can't find user_id in Signature. I
hate to say it, but mostly I've been putting in :foreign_key whereever I think
they might help to no avail.

```
    class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :card
        belongs_to :signer, :class_name => "User"
    end


    class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
        # Correct
        has_many :signatures
        has_many :signers, :through => :signatures, :source => :user

    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        # Wrong!
        has_many :signatures, :foreign_key => "signer_id"
        has_many :signed_cards, :through => :signatures, :source => :card
    end
```

With the error (minus stack trace)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >   u15.signed_cards
  Card Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "signatures" ON "cards"."id" = "signatures"."card_id" WHERE "signatures"."user_id" = 15 ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: signatures.user_id: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "signatures" ON "cards"."id" = "signatures"."card_id" WHERE "signatures"."user_id" = 15 ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: signatures.user_id: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "signatures" ON "cards"."id" = "signatures"."card_id" WHERE "signatures"."user_id" = 15 ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC
```

`Card.signers` returns an empty array as expected.

Still looking for some help on this one. I haven't been able to locate much in the way of simple, straightforward explanations of this where you're not using the same names (i.e. you need a foreign_key and source.

Answer (score 12):

**User** should be defined like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :sent_cards, :class_name => "Card", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :received_cards, :class_name => "Card", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"

  has_many :signatures
  has_many :signed_cards, :through => :signatures, :source => :card

end
```

When your association name is different than the name used at the **:through** you have to define the **source** parameter. If you look at the exception message it **explicitly** asks you to do it.

Comment: OK, with that change I get the following (minus the stack trace) ...

ruby-1.9.2-p0 >   u15.signed_cards
  Card Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "signatures" ON "cards"."id" = "signatures"."card_id" WHERE "signatures"."user_id" = 15 ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: signatures.user_id: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "signatures" ON "cards"."id" = "signatures"."card_id" WHERE "signatures"."user_id" = 15 ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC

Comment: and the rest of the error ...

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: signatures.user_id: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "signatures" ON "cards"."id" = "signatures"."card_id" WHERE "signatures"."user_id" = 15 ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC

Comment: @slabounty: has_many :signatures needs `:foreign_key => :signer_id` on there. It's expecting the field to be called `user_id`.

Comment: @RyanBigg that was actually on my original code.

-- Nevermind, wrong model. Let me give that a shot.

Answer (score 6):

OK, since I had such a hard time with this, I wanted to show everyone what the
final version looked like. A good part of the reason I had such a hard time
firguring this out, was the fact that the rails console didn't seem to be
reloading things correctly as I made changes. I didn't realize this until I
gave up one night, came back the next morning and the case that had been
working the previous night wasn't and the case that wasn't working was.

The migration is the same, but I'll repeat it for completeness sake.

```
def change
    create_table :signatures do |t|
        t.integer :signer_id
        t.integer :card_id
        t.boolean :signed,    :default => false
        t.text :message

        t.timestamps
    end
end
```

The Signature class has the two belongs_to with card being the case that
normally gets shown in the examples and the signer being of type user.

```
class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :card
    belongs_to :signer, :class_name => "User"
end
```

The User has many signatures (necessary even if you don't use them directly)
an dmany signed_cards through signatures with a source of card (telling Rails
which class type the signed_cards are.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :signatures, :foreign_key => "signer_id"
    has_many :signed_cards, :through => :signatures, :source => :card 
end
```

Finally, the Card has many signatures (once again necessary) and many signers
through signatures and the foreign_key for the signer of signer_id.

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :signatures
    has_many :signers, :through => :signatures, :foreign_key => 'signer_id'
end
```

Hopefully, this will help others having similar issues.

Comment: The rails console doesn't pick up changes to your code unless you call `reload!` (and even then it won't pick up things that like changes to gems or initializers)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thanks! I figured it was like Rails itself where things are picked up automatically.