# Has_many through for multiple attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many-through

I am trying to build a model where a **user** has many **roles** like: skills, services, projects and so on, through one table.

I've been fighting all day to get just the skills table to work, having modeled it as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :roles
    has_many :skills, through: :roles

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
end


class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

The closest I can get is this error.

```
skill.users
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "user" or :users in model Role. Try 'has_many :users, :through => :roles, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?
```

here is the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160728053925) do

  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "userSkill"
    t.integer  "skillUser"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["skillUser", "userSkill"], name: "index_relationships_on_skillUser_and_userSkill", unique: true
    t.index ["skillUser"], name: "index_relationships_on_skillUser"
    t.index ["userSkill"], name: "index_relationships_on_userSkill"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "skill_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["skill_id"], name: "index_roles_on_skill_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_roles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "zipcode"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

That relationships table is a renegade from a since destroyed migration, and doesn't belong there, but I can deal with how to delete it on my own.

Anyway, what am I missing? And am I on the right track, and how do I get my has_many through working so I can assign a skill to a user.

The ultimate idea is that many users can have the same skills..

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, firstname: "Jeremy", lastname: "*****", zipcode: nil, email: "*****@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-07-28 05:40:45", updated_at: "2016-07-28 05:40:45", password_digest: "$2a$10$gGkUlUXDVrVtYzHzDdnPQenVrX8sxoXkgdIVeHxIQPr...", remember_digest: nil, admin: true, activation_digest: "$2a$10$6isSjCt3dnVDxEq4HKLBbOTkKFBOEDV8my94rdfZQJL...", activated: true, activated_at: "2016-07-28 05:40:45", reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil>
irb(main):047:0> skill = Skill.find 1
  Skill Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "skills".* FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Skill id: 1, name: "comedy", created_at: "2016-07-28 05:53:56", updated_at: "2016-07-28 05:53:56">
irb(main):048:0> user.skills
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "skill" or :skills in model Role. Try 'has_many :skills, :through => :roles, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:914:in `check_validity!'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:235:in `new'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:235:in `association'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:111:in `skills'
    from (irb):48
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/jeremy/dareal/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
irb(main):049:0> skill.users
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "user" or :users in model Role. Try 'has_many :users, :through => :roles, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:914:in `check_validity!'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:235:in `new'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:235:in `association'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:111:in `users'
    from (irb):49
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/jeremy/dareal/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/jeremy/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Just recreated your structure and it worked fine for me. Show the full stack trace please.

Comment: @Jeremy  can you give the more logs.. ?? when you get error..?? you tried skill.users.. okay than what is in your skill object..??

Comment: Did you visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621630/rails-activerecordhasmanythroughsourceassociationnotfounderror-could-not-fin)

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke that has to do with differing key and association naming convention. I literally just built his project and it works fine.

Comment: what command adds a skill to a user or vice versa?

Added some more of the error output from the console.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you. I tried the same code as you have (copy pasted everything from your sample). All seems to work fine for me. Still can't figure out the problem you are facing. Did you restart the rails console after making the changes?

Comment: Yeah repeatedly but I can try again.